# How to create new page in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x, custom-pages

I am using **Opencart Version 2.0.3.1.**

I have to create new page in Opencart. But I don't know how to start. So I followed the given link http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=6253 to create custom page.

But I got the error

> Fatal error: Cannot access private property Document::$title in
>   C:\wamp\www\opencart\catalog\controller\custom\service.php on line 6

As mentioned in the link,I created three files are:

**catalog/controller/custom/service.php**

```
class ControllerCustomService extends Controller {
   public function index() {
      $this->language->load('custom/service');

      $this->document->title          = $this->language->get('heading_title');


      $this->document->breadcrumbs = array();

         $this->document->breadcrumbs[] = array(
             'href'      => $this->url->http('common/home'),
             'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'separator' => FALSE
         );

      $url = '';

      if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
         $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
      }   

         $this->document->breadcrumbs[] = array(
             'href'      => $this->url->http('custom/service' . $url),
             'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
         );

      $this->data['heading_title']    = $this->language->get('heading_title');
      $this->data['heading_text']      = $this->language->get('heading_text');
      $this->id                   = 'content';
      $this->template             = $this->config->get('config_template') . 'custom/service.tpl';
      $this->layout               = 'common/layout';

      $this->render();
   }
}
```

**catalog/view/theme/default/template/custom/service.tpl**

```
<div class="top">
  <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
</div>
<div class="middle">
  <div><?php echo $heading_text; ?></div>

</div>
<div class="bottom">&nbsp;</div>
```

**catalog/language/custom/service.php**

```
// Heading 
$_['heading_title'] = 'Our Services';

//Content
$_['heading_text'] = 'Welcome to our services';
```

Also I tried the fixes mentioned in that link, but no luck.

So someone please help me to fix the problems... Any help is really appreciable ..

Answer (score 3):

It should be `$this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));`.

And the referral link is for version 1.5.x (for older versions).You should refer files of new version and then create your new files by referring it.

**Edit**

The procedure is same, but you have to check for syntax changes. As in `opencart 
2.x` and above version they have changed a lot of things and syntax.

**Edit**

To load common controllers like `header,footer etc` do this (For version 2.x)

```
$data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
$data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
$data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
$data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
$data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
```

> To load the view

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/directory/viewfile.tpl')) {
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/directory/viewfile.tpl', $data));
} else {
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/directory/viewfile.tpl', $data));
}
```

Comment: I change the file in controller(there are a lot to change), now it is working, but failed to load the header, footer sidebar, breadcrumbs etc

Comment: Ok! I'll show you how to create it. I'll edit my answer.